# AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'mtrand'

Tags: python, numpy, import, attributeerror

After having installed the `pyclustertend` package with `pip install pyclustertend`, I now try to import it into Python:

`from pyclustertent import ivat`

However, I get the following error while doing so:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
from pyclustertend import ivat

File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyclustertend_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
from .hopkins import hopkins  # noqa: F401

```
  File "C:\Users\Emil\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyclustertend\hopkins.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone

  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT

  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .fixes import parse_version, threadpool_info

  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 47, in <module>
    class loguniform(scipy.stats.reciprocal):

  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 1601, in __init__
    super(rv_continuous, self).__init__(seed)

  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py", line 588, in __init__
    self._random_state = check_random_state(seed)

  File "C:\Users\Emil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 202, in check_random_state
    return np.random.mtrand._rand

AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'mtrand'
```

I suspected this has to do with the Numpy version. However, during the installation, it updated numpy to an older version:

```
Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.23.4
Successfully installed numpy-1.20.3 pyclustertend-1.8.2
```

What do I need to do to use this package?